# Python interpreter crashes when trying import

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, biopython

I've got a bigger program and wanted to make it available to people with little knowledge to command lines. Therefore I've made a GUI for it with tkinter. In tests within the IDE everything works fine. Then I tried to start it simply by double clicking in windows on the python program. Apparently The Python Interpreter instantly closes right after the start. Then I tried to run it from the windows command line. Everything fine without any exception.
I then tried to debug with input() to find the line causing the crash.
I turns out that it closes the window when trying to import Bio. Bio is the module from the biopython package. (Never understood why these names are different). When I open a python shell and try to import Bio this works fine as well.
I am working with python 3.7.
So any suggestions?

```
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import filedialog
input()
from Bio import SeqIO,SeqFeature,Seq

from copy import deepcopy
```

EDIT: I just tried to import Bio in my tests. While this works fine, it gives an exception when trying from Bio import SeqIO,SeqFeature,Seq.

```
>>> from Bio import SeqIO,SeqFeature,Seq
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\alb18\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\Bio\SeqIO\__init__.py", line 382, in <module>
    from Bio.Align import MultipleSeqAlignment
  File "C:\Users\alb18\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\Bio\Align\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from Bio.Align import _aligners
ImportError: cannot import name '_aligners' from 'Bio.Align' (C:\Users\alb18\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\Bio\Align\__init__.py)
```

I do not understand the error though.

Comment: We can't offer any definitive help without knowing what the error actually is. Are you sure you are using the same interpreter that you installed `biopython` to?

Comment: Take a look to which `python` executable the `.py` extension is connected to. I guess a different one than in your `PATH`...

Comment: Well this sounds like a good idea. Checked Path variables:
C:\Users\alb18\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\
C:\Users\alb18\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\
C:\Users\alb18\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\
C:\Users\alb18\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\
The executable from C:\Users\alb18\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\ is the one I tried to open the program with.

Comment: Also tried: run this exectuable, opening a python shell and import Bio. Works fine.